# Ordernar por mes em power bi

Tags: powerbi

Eu tenho uma planilha em excel que me da algo do tipo

```
Contrato      Jan/2018       Fev/2018       Mar/2018
2010100       15.800,00      9.000,00       15.000,00
2010101       10.000,00     10.000,50       11.000,15
```

Logo em seguida fiz um *unpivot* desses dados resultando em algo parecido com isso

```
Contrato      Jan/2018       Fev/2018    Mar/2018     Attribute      Value
2010100       15.800,00      9.000,00    15.000,00    Jan/2018       15.800,00
2010100       15.800,00      9.000,00    15.000,00    Fev/2018        9.000,00
2010100       15.800,00      9.000,00    15.000,00    Mar/2018       15.000,00
2010101       10.000,00     10.000,50    11.000,15    Jan/2018       10.000,00
2010101       10.000,00     10.000,50    11.000,15    Fev/2018       11.000,15
2010101       10.000,00     10.000,50    11.000,15    Mar/2018       10.000,50
```

Logo em seguida, eu crio um *line chart* puxando como dados o "Attibute e "Value", mas só que a ordem de exibição fica na ordem alfabética e queria colocar nas ordens dos meses, como jan/2018, fev/2018 e mar/2018

Já tentei ir em *modeling* e *sort by column* mas não ordena pela ordem do mês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabriel nesse caso voce pode fazer o seguinte.

Crie uma tabela auxiliar de **'TEMPO'**, nessa tabela deverá conter seus meses/anos (da mesma forma como aparecem na sua tabela atual) e uma outra coluna que pode ser chamada 'ORDEM' por exemplo.

Mais ou menos nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso faça o vínculo dessa nova tabela com a sua tabela original ( Pelo campo de DATA)

Feito isso voce precisa selecionar o menu de dados no PowerBI, clicar na coluna de 'DATA' e então alterar a classificação da coluna para ser classificada **por outra coluna**  (ORDEM). Conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso o powerbi vai começar a ordernar a coluna data pela 'ORDEM' conforme voce selecionou.

Só lembrando que essa coluna (DATA) é que tem de ser colocada nos seus gráficos/tabelas, para que ele obedeça essa regra de ordenação.

**Importante**

A coluna de ordem deve estar selecionada com o tipo de dados **'NUMERO INTEIRO'** para que a ordenação seja feita da forma adequada.

**Obs.**:

Esse mesmo processo pode ser feito na sua tabela atual criando uma coluna personalizada e atribuindo a ordem para cada mês/ano respectivamente. Para voce isso voce pode utilizar alguma função **DAX**

Comment: Amigão, acabei adotando uma solução bem parecida com essa, embora já havia conseguido resolver a um tempo atrás. 

De qualquer forma fico profundamente agradecido pelo tempo dedicado para escrever essa respota.